# Handling deletion of Mentions/tags like that in Facebook

Tags: javascript, react-native

So I am trying to implement the tagging feature that is present on Facebook on my own for an app that I am building using React Native. The trigger for suggestions is capital letters. What I do is, as the user is typing, the string is split into individual words using `str.split(" ")`. Then I simply take the last element of the `str.split(" ")` array and make a query with that for fetching suggestions. Once a person selects a particular suggestion, I simply add that suggestion to an array which I can send along with the text. Now I am not sure how to implement the case where a person has written a long post tagging various people and now wants to delete a particular mention in the middle of the post.  Any help will be super useful.

Comment: Use Draft JS. :)

Comment: @Victor I think DraftJS is for React only. Does it work with React Native as well? Will have to check.

Answer (score 0):

First you need a function that check the availability of the array members in the string, you can easily do this with find function .

You can call this function each time the user delete a word , you can do it by checking the length of the string

It's obvious this will affect the performance for handling it you can call the function after the user pressed the submit button and delete the extra mentioned users .

Best regards.

Comment: The thing is I am also saving start index and end index of the mention so that i can use those indices to format the mentions by making it bold or highlighting it. So once a user deletes a mention at a particular line how do I update the start and end indices of the other mentions.

Comment: You don't need to save the position of the mentions. You have to just check the whole string and compare it with the current mentions array in the end